# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout when used Retrofit with use or without use of OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit2, socketexception

I just used Retrofit without OkHttp.
Here is my code

```
private void executeForm(String pubToken,String acctToken,Integer Amt,String UID){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/plaidCredentialsAddMoney/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();

        APIService apiservice=retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<PostData> call=apiservice.achPost(pubToken,acctToken,Amt,UID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostData> call, Response<PostData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    response.body();
                    String dp = response.body().getToken();
                    Log.d(TAG,dp);

                    Toast.makeText(ACH.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostData> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG,t.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

I aslo added OkHttp3 by researching the error.Here is the part that deals with OkHttp3

```
OkHttpClient OClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/plaidCredentialsAddMoney/")
                .client(OClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();
```

But I got the same error.I think there is no need to add OkHttp3 for the error because previusly I worked with Retrofit without using OkHttp then it worked as expected.
Here is the log output

```
03-24 16:16:45.591 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:593)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:601)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:146)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:125)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.592 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-24 16:16:45.593 28361-28361/com.bodaty.deyaPay.deyaPay E/MyActivity: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `writeTimeout()` :

```
OkHttpClient OClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
OClient.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: doesn't and will not work if writing request exceeds 5 minutes.

Comment: well it worked for me and some other people. Maybe something changed 3 years later though.